# "Could not retrieve the required disk image files" when using wubi.exe + iso in same folder

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I've downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 iso + wubi installer and put the both of them in the same directory. I get an error when running the installer (with no internet connection). Here's the log: http://pastebin.com/Tzv4EwNX What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to install the 64 bit version on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
03-18 01:11 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO C:\Users\Ofer\Desktop\ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
03-18 01:11 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain casper\vmlinuz
```

I know this is an existing bug in the development release 13.04, but I wasn't aware it was in 12.04.2 as well. There is no workaround to this, because you'd have to update the ISO (possible but painful).

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770 (just updated with this latest info).

**Workarounds**

You could either use the 12.04.1 Wubi.exe with the 12.04.1 ISO available at [old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/)
Or you could use the 12.10 Wubi.exe plus the 12.10 ISO.

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest wubi release from http://ftp.ticklers.org/releases.ubuntu.org/releases//precise/wubi.exe

Put this in the ISO and replace the previous file. You should be good now.

Comment: worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have just successfully installed ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386 using [the latest wubi version](http://ftp.ticklers.org/releases.ubuntu.org/releases//precise/wubi.exe); as **Igniterminator** said: early days.

But before that I failed to install it by the  wubi supplied in the `.iso` file. I referred to the log file and found out that one of the causes was that the iso-inclued wubi only supported 12.04.2 but not 12.04.3. I guessed that the older wubi was integrated to the newer `.iso` file by mistake.

BTW, another problem prevented me from installation is that wubi automatically downloaded the amd64 version, though I chose to install the i386 version. I solved this problem by runing  Wubi from the command prompt with the `--32bit` argument (you can refer to the [Wubi guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)).

To sum up, used the latest wubi and forced the wubi to install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, and I managed to install it. (And I pray that my poor English can express my self. XD)